# Why does Mathematica fail to series expand this simple expression?

Tags: series-expansion

I wanted to expand the function $(x+2)^{x+2}$ around $x = -1$, that is, using

```
Series[(x + 2)^(x + 2), {x, -1, 2}]
```

and *Mathematica* returns the same expression. Why does this happen? The first term of a series expansion is simply $1^1 = 1$. However, I cannot even get this, from

```
Series[(x + 2)^(x + 2), {x, -1, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: This `Series[(x + 2)^(x + 2), {x, x0, 2}] /. x0 -> -1` works.

Comment: Both expressions work here with Mathematica 8.0.1. `Series[(x + 2)^(x + 2), {x, -1, 2}]` gives `1 + (x+1) + (x+1)^2 + O[x+1]^3`. And `Series[(x + 2)^(x + 2), {x, -1, 0}]` gives `1 + O[x+1]^1`. Do you use a fresh kernel?

Comment: @b.gatessucks: It indeed works. However, this is such a random error, that I was hoping someone could point out what's going on with the system. Thank you for the workaround, though.

Comment: @partial81 Yes, fresh kernel.

Comment: Yes, fresh kernel. See the output png file in the new edit. This is with Mathematica 9. By the way, @b.gatessucks: your workaround gives errors if the series is about a singular point. In that case, the workaround requires two series expansions (once for the x0, and once more again for the proper value)

Comment: I see, thanks for the screenshot. I do not have Mathematica 9 on this computer, so I cannot test it. Perhaps the reason is your Mac?

Comment: Very odd.  Translate it and it works, e.g., `Series[(x + 3)^(x + 3), {x, -2, 2}]` gives `1+(x+2)+(x+2)^2+O[x+2]^3`.  (v9.0.1)

Comment: Ok, just as confirmation: `Series[(x + 2)^(x + 2), {x, -1, 2}]` gives `1 + (x+1) + (x+1)^2 + O[x+1]^3` with v8.0.1 but `(2 + x)^(2 + x)` with v9.0.0. Seems to be a bug in the new version. This brings me to two questions: 1. Where to report such a bug? 2. Does Wolfram provide updates so that one can work with a software which has less bugs?

Comment: @partial81 ad 1) Use Help>Give Feedback, ad 2) Often there will be one or two minor updates (eg. 8.0.1) which fix some bugs.

Answer (score 1):

For version 9

```
$Version
```

> "9.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 24, 2013)"

```
f[x_] = (x + 2)^(x + 2);

f2[x_] = (Series[(x + 2)^(x + 2), {x, a, 2}] // Normal) /. a -> -1
```

> 2 + x + (1 + x)^2

```
Plot[{f[x], f2[x]}, {x, -2.5, 0}]
```